# Why is this apartment's area reported much bigger than sum of its rooms' areas?

Tags: bedroom

[image]

My calculation is roughly that the total area is two times the sum of the area of living room and the area of the bigger bedroom:

(13*17+10.5*15)*2 = 757.0 (sq Ft).

However it shows the apartment is approximately 905 sq Ft, which is about 150 sq Ft larger than my calculation, i.e. almost the size of the bigger bedroom. So I wonder where there is such a big difference? Is this common for apartments and houses?

Comment: The 'approximately' is likely a bit of a license to err on the side of larger, but looking at the floor plan, it doesn't look like closets and such are being counted on the room dimensions.

Comment: As others pointed out, it is a calculation of living space, and people don't live in walls, closets, unfinished basements or attics or garages.

Answer (score 2):

As DA01 commented, the total apartment area appears to be calculated as everything within the external walls, whereas the rooms are calculated as the volume of each room **minus** the space taken up by closets, wardrobes etc.

A quick visual check seems to bear this out - the size of those closets and unusable spaces added together would just about fill the larger bedroom.